# AWS Glue Crawler exclude option not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, anti-patterns

I have s3 bucket as bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3. Inside folder3 I have two csv files such as report.csv and report.csv_abcd.csv. I have tried multiple regex to exclude the report.csv_abcd.csv which works fine in regex test but doesn't work for glue. Glue is picking both files and adding in the same table as both of the file have same schema. I have given s3 data source as s3://bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3/ and regex to exclude report.csv_abcd.csv as **/!(report.csv_*)*.csv